# How To Make CASE Statement To Iterate Over All Patterns Even When A Match Is Found

Tags: case

How do I make the case command below to continue matching the next pattern even after it matches "apple" without jumping to the end of the case flow

```
#!/bin/sh
FRUIT="apple"
case "$FRUIT" in
"apple") echo "Apple pie is quite tasty."
;;
"banana") echo "I like banana nut bread."
;;
"kiwi") echo "New Zealand is famous for kiwi."
;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question through experiment. I just changed `;;` to `;;&` and it worked!